# How do I update the join table in EFCore6 Code-First for Many-to-many relationships?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, ef-code-first

I am trying to create a School Management System using .NET WPF Application.
My database is build with **EFCore6**, **Code-First**.

I have two classes and there is a Many-to-Many relationship between them.

````
`public class Subject
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    public ICollection<Specialization> Specializations { get; set; } = null!;

    public Subject()
    {
        
    }
}

public class Specialization
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Subject> Subjects { get; set; } = null!;
    

    public Specialization() {
        Id = 0;
        Name = string.Empty;
    }
}```
````

I have also configured the relationships using the DbContext's model builder:
//SPECIALIZATION-SUBJECT
`modelBuilder.Entity<Specialization>() .HasMany(e => e.Subjects) .WithMany(e => e.Specializations) .UsingEntity( "SpecializationSubject", l => l.HasOne(typeof(Subject)).WithMany().HasForeignKey("SubjectId").HasPrincipalKey(nameof(Subject.Id)), r =>        r.HasOne(typeof(Specialization)).WithMany().HasForeignKey("SpecializationId").HasPrincipalKey(nameof(Specialization.Id)), j => j.HasKey("SpecializationId", "SubjectId"));`

This created a **specializationsubject** table in my database which contains a SpecializationId and a SubjectId.

I have manually added into the database a few Specializations. Now, when I try to add from my UI a new Subject, if the ICollection of Specializations in my Subject class is not empty, I get the following error:
**MySqlException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'specializations.PRIMARY'.**

I want the table **specializationsubject** to be updated when I add a new subject which is linked to existing specializations.

I don't really find nothing useful on internet

Answer (score 0):

for many to many relationship you have to create another model that contain both table.

```
public class SpecializedSubject
{
  public int SubjectId { get; set; }
  public int SpecializationId { get; set; }

  public Subject SubjectObj { get; set; } = null;
  public Specialization SpecializationObj{ get; set; } = null;

}
```

Note: before create relation, you have to delete all the data from the table. becuse if there is data that can't be match relation then it will show error

Comment: It seems like I've been using two different instances of dbContext - one when I read the information from the database and one when I tried to update the information.